# Converting a .gif to a .ani and Keeping All the Frames

Tags: c#, image, file

How can I convert a .gif to a .ani and maintain all the frames from the gif when converting over to ani in C#?

Comment: Try copying and pasting the text of your question into ChatGPT.

Comment: @Enigmativity Haha I already did that multiple times, and it did not give me a working answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to find any .NET libraries for writing ANI-files. However, if running a command to call an external executable is an option, [ani-gif](https://github.com/mzntori/ani-gif) is a CLI written in Rust for converting GIFs to ANI. No pre-built binaries are available at the time of writing, so you would have to build it yourself using [Cargo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/index.html):

```
git clone https://github.com/mzntori/ani-gif.git
cd ./ani-gif
cargo build --release
```

`ani-gif.exe` can then be found in `./ani-gif/target/release`. This executable can be called from C# as follows:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

const string cliPath = @"path\to\ani-gif.exe";

void ConvertGifToAni(string gifPath, string aniPath, uint frameRate, string hotSpot="0:0")
{
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = cliPath,
        ArgumentList =
        {
            "convert",
            "-g",
            gifPath,
            "-a",
            aniPath,
            "-f",
            frameRate.ToString(),
            "--hotspot",
            hotSpot,
        },
        CreateNoWindow = true,
    };
    var proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
    proc?.WaitForExit();
}

ConvertGifToAni(
    gifPath: @"path\to\cursor.gif",
    aniPath: @"path\to\cursor.ani",
    frameRate: 5);
```

This should retain all of the original frames.